# products.sqlalchemypas-1.0-py2.6.egg AttributeError: getGroupsForPrincipal

Tags: plone

I am using products.sqlalchemypas-1.0-py2.6.egg for authenticating user from MSSQL Table. Authentication work as expected but now I'm trying implementaing groups plugin to
get groups from different table. What happening is when I'm trying to loggin its giving me error saying AttributeError: getGroupsForPrincipal.

Error Traceback is ..

2012-02-21T15:33:14 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests

---

2012-02-21T15:39:25 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1329838765.580.598770330561 http://localhost:8060/dev/login_form

```
Traceback (innermost last):

 Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 115, in publish
 Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 596, in traverse
 Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 235, in validate
 Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 735, in _findUser
 Module Products.PluggableAuthService.PluggableAuthService, line 668, in   _getGroupsForPrincipal
 AttributeError: getGroupsForPrincipal
```

My defination in plugin.py is ...

```python
def getGroupsForPrincipal(self, principal=getSecurityManager().getUser().getId(),request=None):
    "Getting groups from SIMS"
     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
     groups = []
     results = self.simsGroupForUser(username=principal)
     for row in results.dictionaries():
        group = row.get('group')
        groups.append(group)
        return groups
```

Don't know why its not able to reach this method in plugin.py however there is implatemented block where I did define this interface to implement resulting showing groups interface in my acl_user pas object.

[added]
I've tried to import my plugin in debugger and tried to reach this method and have same error so I dont know Do I need to define anything specifically to pick this method in my pas. I did define in my implements class to impelement IGroupsPlugin.

Any comment is great help as always.

Comment: Please post the full traceback, so the complete text starting with 'Traceback (innermost last)' and ending with 'AttributeError: getGroupsForPrincipal'.  Above I only see the first few lines.

Comment: That's complete (only) traceback I'm getting from site

Comment: Yep, looks good now.  Either you have edited it since last time I looked, or I overlooked the last line of the traceback.  Or my browser is playing tricks on me. :-)

Comment: No worries. All sorted. should be releasing this product too very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that My file has wrong indentation, that why it was giving attributes error. Thanks all for your time and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you method definition does what you expect it to. `principal=getSecurityManager().getUser().getId()` will calculate the default parameter at import time rather than at method execution time.

Comment: Any case my method is not found by pas, resulting in attributeserror. I appericiates about your point but I'm not reaching there in PAS